# How used last value of variable when application closed?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I want to use an event like as i have some value in string and after storing value in string I have closed the application and now i again run that application. Now i want to use value of string which i save it in last time. How do that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `NSUserDefaults`. you can refer following links

1. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/
2. http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults
3. http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Answer (score 0):

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourString forKey:yourKey]; // SET

yourString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:yourKey]; // GET

Answer (score 0):

U should create a plist file .plist

step 1: #define DataFilePath before @implementation

> ```
> #define DataFilePath                [@"~/Documents/<fileName>.plist" stringByStandardizingPath]
> ```

step 2:create plist File than

> if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:DataFilePath]) 
>     {       NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle
>   mainBundle] pathForResource:@"" ofType:@"plist"]];
>                 [data writeToFile:DataFilePath atomically:TRUE];        [data release];     }       NSData *data = [NSData
>   dataWithContentsOfFile:DataFilePath];     NSLog(@"%@",DataFilePath);
>     NSPropertyListFormat format;    NSArray *array =
>   [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
>   mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format
>   errorDescription:nil];

step 3: save  to plist file

> NSString *path = [[CommonFunctions documentsDirectory]
>   stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",];
>    NSLog(@" file path = %@",path);    [data writeToFile:path atomically:TRUE];